# Delay hiding automatic scroll bar in Mac OS

Tags: macos, scroll, scrollbar

Is there a way to adjust the delay time for hiding the automatically appearing scroll bar in Mac OS?

Currently, after scrolling a page, the scroll bar appears for less than a second before disappearing. If you are trying to grab the bar to manually adjust scroll position, that isn't a lot of time.

Is there some sort of terminal command that can double the length of the delay before the scroll bar hides again?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but have you looked into not hiding or the other settings available? http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/03/show-scroll-bars-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: I have, I prefer them to normally be hidden (most apps now optimize for that and look ugly with "Always" enabled), but in the semi-rare instance when I need to manually scroll I find it very annoying having to scroll and then quickly try to grab the scroll bar before it disappears. My hope is for some random terminal command that adjusts the delay time, if something like that exists.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: *Bump* I'm trying to find a way to shorten the time...